# Unable to remove padding from material-ui TabPane

Tags: css, material-ui

I have this `TabPane`:
[image]

I have been trying to remove the padding. According to some answers on SO, this is what I need to do:

```
  <TabPanel
      value={value}
      index={i}
      classes={{
        "& .MuiBox-root": {
          padding: "0px",
        },
      }}
    >
```

But, this had no effect.

When I inspected the page, I found out I had to remove `MuiBox-root-9` to remove the padding. Removing `MuiBox-root` had no effect:

```
<div class="MuiBox-root MuiBox-root-9">
```

And I don't know how to target that class `MuiBox-root-9`.

Comment: Hi, could you please specify which version of the Material UI are you using?

Comment: Anyhow, I updated the [codepen](https://codesandbox.io/s/basictabs-material-demo-forked-fpm1b?file=/demo.js) (MUI v5), which uses the new `Styled` api by MUI, introduced in the V5. Here is [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-mhz4w?file=/demo.js) demo using the MUI v4. in MUI v4, I targeted the class provided by the Tabpanel API to add the styling from the higher classes in the DOM.

Comment: The way you're styling using the classes prop `classes={{ "& .MuiBox-root": {padding:"0px", }, }}` is not going to work. In order to style using the `classes` prop, you need to pass an object containing the keys matching the css rule name, containing a class key. You can see the available rule names for a particular component in its API section in the docs. E.g. this is the [tab](https://mui.com/api/tab/#css) API showing the available rule names for the tab compoent

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if I'm not mistaken the `TabPanel` is the component you created not the one from material so if you following [this example](https://mui.com/components/tabs/#BasicTabs.js).

```js
function TabPanel(props) {
  const { children, value, index, ...other } = props;

  return (
    <div
      role="tabpanel"
      hidden={value !== index}
      id={`simple-tabpanel-${index}`}
      aria-labelledby={`simple-tab-${index}`}
      {...other}
    >
      {value === index && (
        <Box sx={{ p: 3 }}>
          <Typography>{children}</Typography>
        </Box>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

you can just remove `sx={{ p: 3 }}` to make your panel has no `padding`.

Comment: Yup. This solveed my problem. Except that I did p:0

Answer (score 1):

Simply use sx prop in MUI to override the CSS properties.

```
  <TabPanel
    value={value}
    index={i}
    sx={{ p: 0 }}
  >
  </TabPanel>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).